# Python reading tags in string, json?

Tags: python, string

I'm using a telnet api for logitech media server for functions not included in pylms python library.

I'm stuck handling the response of a request.

Below is an example of a response as a single string

```
players 0 2 count:2 playerindex:0 playerid:a5:41:d2:cd:cd:05 ip:127.0.0.1:60488 name:127.0.0.1 model:softsqueeze displaytype:graphic-280x16 connected:1 playerindex:1 playerid:00:04:20:02:00:c8 ip:192.168.1.22:3483 name:Movy model:slimp3 displaytype:noritake-katakana connected:1
```

I want to extract name and ip tags for the above example.  Looking on Internet is this json formating?  Ive tried reading with json.load and json.dump python module but no luck.  The closes ive got is using. `split(" ")` and then `split(":")`  but this falls over when a tag is made up of two words ie contains a space.

To sum it up how do I get a list of "name: " tags?

Comment: I wasn't sure thats why i asked "json formating ?" in my question.  But from your answer it looks like is not.

Comment: Yeah i am very new on here i don't understand why you say my tone is non constructive,  i wasn't sure if this was a json formating. I dont mean to affend i was just after advice.  Sorry if any misunderstanding.

Comment: So if you say that tags can contain spaces, then how is ``players count:2`` parsed — as ``players``, ``count:2`` or ``"players count":2``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of exactly the type of output you want but I think I have an idea of how to create a useful data structure using a regex, with the `'name'` and `'ip'` tags.

From a repl:

```
In [38]: str = 'players 0 2 count:2 playerindex:0 playerid:a5:41:d2:cd:cd:05 ip:127.0.0.1:60488 name:127.0.0.1 model:softsqueeze displaytype:graphic-280x16 connected:1 playerindex:1 playerid:00:04:20:02:00:c8 ip:192.168.1.22:3483 name:Movy model:slimp3 displaytype:noritake-katakana connected:1'

In [39]: regex = re.compile(r'([^:]+):(\S+)\s')

In [40]: regex.findall(str)
Out[40]: 
[('players 0 2 count', '2'),
 ('playerindex', '0'),
 ('playerid', 'a5:41:d2:cd:cd:05'),
 ('ip', '127.0.0.1:60488'),
 ('name', '127.0.0.1'),
 ('model', 'softsqueeze'),
 ('displaytype', 'graphic-280x16'),
 ('connected', '1'),
 ('playerindex', '1'),
 ('playerid', '00:04:20:02:00:c8'),
 ('ip', '192.168.1.22:3483'),
 ('name', 'Movy'),
 ('model', 'slimp3'),
 ('displaytype', 'noritake-katakana')]
```

To extract the name and ip tags, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = regex.findall(str)
In [45]: name_and_ip_tags = [x for x in lst if x[0] in ['ip', 'name']]

In [46]: name_and_ip_tags
Out[46]: 
[('ip', '127.0.0.1:60488'),
 ('name', '127.0.0.1'),
 ('ip', '192.168.1.22:3483'),
 ('name', 'Movy')]
```

The regex

```
([^:]+):(\S+)\s
```

works like so:

First the `([^:]+)` matches everything other then a `:` one or more times, and the parenthesis around this part of the regex store it as the first capture of the match.

The `:` literal simply matches a `:`.

`(\S+)` matches everything other than a space, one or more times (due to the `+`) and the parenthesis make it the second part captured by the match.

`\s` matches a single space, which seems to separate all of your records.

Calling `regex.findall(str)` tries to match the `regex` on `str` as many times as it can. The output is a `list` of 2-tuples, where the first element of every tuple is the match from the first capturing parenthesis of the regex and the second element is the match from the second capturing parenthesis of the regex.

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for more details on regexes in Python.

Comment: First off thanks for your well explained reply. Your code works well on the given example but its falling over where i got to using loads of split string functions.  I.e. when the name tag contains a space ie ""name: test test" the space in the tag seems to upset everything. Sorry i should of put on in on my string example.  Although i think regex is the way forward.  Im thinking looking between "name:" and "model:"  tags shouldn't contain the whole name tag even if it contains a space.  Any ideas??  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2873882 Can you please provide a sample string which contains a space in some of the values? Also, there has to be some way to separate the values from the keys. I assumed it was a space, but if the string was something like "key one: value one key two: value 2", then I am not sure how you could tell which part of the substring "value one key two" belongs to the second key and which part belongs to the first value.

Comment: Ok sample string#   players 0 2 count:2 playerindex:0 playerid:a5:41:d2:cd:cd:05 ip:127.0.0.1:60488 name:127.0.0.1 model:softsqueeze displaytype:graphic-280x16 connected:1 playerindex:1 playerid:00:04:20:02:00:c8 ip:192.168.1.22:3483 name:down stairs model:slimp3 displaytype:noritake-katakana connected:1   Note "name: down stairs " its only the tag item text that may contain a space,  the tag name doesn't.  So its not possible to look between  name: and model to pick up the complete name item? Cheers again.

Comment: @user2873882 Try setting `regex = re.compile(r'([^:]+):(.*?)\s(?=[^: ]+:)')`, and following along with the rest of my example to make sure it is what you want. If this gives you the correct answer, let me know and I will update my answer with further explanation as to how it works. If not, also let me know what doesn't work. Happy coding :)

Comment: That Works a treat! Exactly what i was after. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the info. I haven't tried it in Python, but I think [this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uuahp1ZnRio2jDS1) should work. It might help if you tell us what the expected result is.

```
import re
regex = re.compile("ip:([^\\ ]{0,})\\ name:([^\\ ]{0,})")
testString = "" # fill this in
matchArray = regex.findall(testString)
# the matchArray variable contains the list of matches
```

(from debuggex.com snippet)

Comment: Your example works well for above code but falls over when the name tag contains a space.  I.e.  "name: test test"  my example string didn't have any spaces inside name tag sodds law.  Any ideas?  Cheers again for your time